# Howard Eves' Introduction to the History of Mathematics -- editions and years published?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Can anyone point me towards where I may be able to find a list of all the editions of Howard Eves' Introduction to the History of Mathematics?

I know little about this book; I understand that it's used in some American universities as a text for their undergraduate History of Mathematics courses.

All the online sources may give the year of publication, or the edition, but apart from 6th edition 1990 I have no idea what was published when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-the-history-of-mathematics/oclc/20842510/editions?referer=di&sd=asc&start_edition=1&se=yr&qt=show_more_yr%3A&cookie=&editionsView=true&fq=&fc=yr%3A_25) appears to give $1953$ for the first edition, $1964$ for the Revised editions, $1969$ for the third edition, $1976$ for the fourth edition, $1983$ for the fifth edition, and $1990$ for the sixth edition. There is one listing for a $1989$ sixth edition, but I suspect that it’s simply an error on someone’s part.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Comment: @PrimeMover: My pleasure.